# How to wrap a binary xcframework Firebase in an SPM package and use it in a project?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm trying to add Firebase as a binary to my project to reduce build time, so far I've tried making my own binary and adding it to the project and it was successful, however, I've run into a problem with a big dependency like Firebase.
I've downloaded Firebase binaries from their [releases page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases), then created a new Swift Package, copied some of the xcframeworks into `artifacts` folder, and then added to `Package.swift` to test if I could use FirebaseAnalytics like this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "FirebaseWrapper",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "FirebaseWrapper",
            targets: ["FirebaseWrapper"]),
        .library(
            name: "FirebaseAnalytics",
            targets: ["FirebaseAnalytics"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "FirebaseWrapper",
            dependencies: [.target(name: "FirebaseAnalytics")]),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FBLPromises", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FBLPromises.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FirebaseAnalyticsSwift", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FirebaseCore", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FirebaseCoreInternal", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCoreInternal.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "FirebaseInstallations", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseInstallations.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "GoogleAppMeasurement", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "GoogleUtilities", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/GoogleUtilities.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "nanopb", path: "artifacts/FirebaseAnalytics/nanopb.xcframework")
    ]
)
```

Then I've added this `FirebaseWrapper` to "Link Binary With Libraries" stage as usual and tried to build, but Xcode gave me a bunch of errors like

```
Undefined symbol: _APMAnalyticsConfiguration
Undefined symbol: _APMAppMeasurementOriginFirebase
...
```

When I expand the detailed log, I see

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'GoogleAppMeasurement'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_APMAnalyticsConfiguration", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics.o)
  "_APMAppMeasurementOriginFirebase", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics.o)
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So it's obvious that I have to do some additional steps when I add some complex binary like this, or I messed up somewhere.

You can find the test project with all these packages to play with here: [github link](https://github.com/smocer/MockAppForTestingThings).

I'd like to ask for advice on how can I fix that, as well as any recommendations for articles/videos/guides on how xcode build system works, how are frameworks/libraries/etc arranged, and so on. So far I've watched these WWDC sessions: [WWDC_1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10147/), [WWDC_2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/), and read the docs from Apple: [doc_1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages), [doc_2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-standalone-swift-package-with-xcode), [doc_3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle), but they gave me only somewhat shallow understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Hi smocer, can you please explain briefly what you did to accomplish this first bit mentioned above: "...so far I've tried making my own binary and adding it to the project and it was successful". Thanks.

Comment: Hi @CaseyPerkins, I was just testing how to create xcframework and add it to the project, so I've created a library consisting of just one swift file (with a public class with some public method), compiled it and added as a binary dependency. I don't remember the steps exactly, but something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad, as it turned out I just had to add all the dependencies of `FirebaseAnalytics` to the dependencies of the main target of my `FirebaseWrapper`:

```
Before:

targets: [
    .target(
        name: "FirebaseWrapper",
        dependencies: [
            .target(name: "FirebaseAnalytics")
        ]),
...
_____________________________________________________________

After:

targets: [
    .target(
        name: "FirebaseWrapper",
        dependencies: [
            .target(name: "FirebaseAnalytics"),
            .target(name: "FBLPromises"),
            .target(name: "FirebaseAnalyticsSwift"),
            .target(name: "FirebaseCore"),
            .target(name: "FirebaseCoreInternal"),
            .target(name: "FirebaseInstallations"),
            .target(name: "GoogleAppMeasurement"),
            .target(name: "GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport"),
            .target(name: "GoogleUtilities"),
            .target(name: "nanopb"),
        ]),
...
```

Now it builds and runs successfully.